# Assigning multiple variables within a one-line conditional

Tags: function, conditional-statements, julia, variable-assignment

In my class on Julia, we were shown this basic implementation of a bubble sort:

```
function bubble_sort!(a)
    n = length(a)
    for i in 1:n-1
        for j in 1:n-i
            if a[j] > a[j+1]
                a[j], a[j+1] = a[j+1], a[j]
            end
        end
    end
    return a
end
```

As an exercise, I'm trying to condense the actual sorting part into a one-line conditional like so:

```
function bubble_sort_oneline!(a::Vector)
    n = length(a)
    for i in 1:n-1
        for j in 1:n-i
            (a[j] > a[j+1]) ? a[j], a[j+1] = a[j+1], a[j] : nothing
        end
    end
    return a
end
```

However, Julia returns a syntax error: 'colon expected in "?" expression. It seems to me like having the comma separating the assignments causes some issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it. How would I be able to do this?

Comment: You won't.  In some languages (C, C++), the `=` operator is just like any other operator,  and can be embedded inside an expression.  In Julia (and Python), `=` is a statement.  The left side and right side basically have to stand alone.  You can't embed it in another expression.  And, frankly, you shouldn't want to.  That's an abomination. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact that the ternary operation has a return value which can be assigned. So put the assignment statement out of the ternary statement like this (this is the beauty in functional languages and expressions, that one can use if else expressions for assignments like this):

```
function bubble_sort_oneline!(a::Vector)
    n = length(a)
    for i in 1:n-1, j in 1:n-i
        a[j], a[j+1] = (a[j] > a[j+1]) ? (a[j+1], a[j]) : (a[j], a[j+1])
    end
    return a
end

# test with:
bubble_sort_oneline!(rand(1:99, 10))
```

You can do this also in Python, if you use the one-liner if-else expression:

```
def bubble_sort(a):
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(n-i-1):
            (a[j], a[j+1]) = (a[j+1], a[j]) if a[j] > a[j+1] else (a[j], a[j+1])
    return a
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write `a[j] > a[j+1] ? begin a[j], a[j+1] = a[j+1], a[j] end : nothing`, or since you don't need the 3rd part of the ternary, use `&&` instead:

```
julia> function bubble_sort!(a)
           n = length(a)
           for i in 1:n-1, j in 1:n-i
               a[j] > a[j+1] && begin a[j], a[j+1] = a[j+1], a[j] end
           end
           return a
       end
bubble_sort! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> bubble_sort!(rand(1:99, 10))'
1×10 adjoint(::Vector{Int64}) with eltype Int64:
 4  18  24  25  28  56  87  89  92  95
```

Without the comma you could use brackets instead of begin/end, but the parser thinks that `a[j] > a[j+1] && (a[j], a[j+1] = a[j+1], a[j])` could be syntax for a NamedTuple, and says `invalid named tuple element "a[j]"`.

```
julia> let x = 3
        rand()>0.1 && (x = 4)
        @show x; nothing
       end
x = 4
```

The original is probably still easier to read, though.

Comment: You could also just use parens: `a[j] > a[j+1] && ((a[j], a[j+1]) = (a[j+1], a[j]))`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the code as short as possible consider broadcasting (this way you have one statement and can avoid `begin ... end`:

```
a[j:j+1] .= (a[j+1], a[j])
```

Some example:

```
julia> a=[1,2,3,4]; j = 2;

julia> 2 > 1 && (a[j:j+1] .= (a[j+1], a[j]));

julia> a'
1×4 adjoint(::Vector{Int64}) with eltype Int64:
 1  3  2  4
```

Comment: Tested the example and it seems parenthesis are required after the `&&`

Comment: yes, thanks - I update. I guess I started testing without the conditional part. Interestingly it "works" without the parenthesis but the values do not get swapped

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the Benchmark of some solution.

```
using Random, BenchmarkTools
Random.seed!(42)
y = rand(1000)

function bubble_sort!(a)  # Orig: mysterymachine
    n = length(a)
    for i in 1:n-1, j in 1:n-i
      if a[j] > a[j+1]
        a[j], a[j+1] = a[j+1], a[j]
      end
    end
    return a
end
@btime bubble_sort!(x) setup=(x=copy(y));
#  834.974 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

function bubble_sort!(a)  # mcabbott
  n = length(a)
  for i in 1:n-1, j in 1:n-i
    a[j] > a[j+1] && begin a[j], a[j+1] = a[j+1], a[j] end
  end
  return a
end
@btime bubble_sort!(x) setup=(x=copy(y));
#  828.920 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

function bubble_sort!(a)  # DNF
  n = length(a)
  for i in 1:n-1, j in 1:n-i
    a[j] > a[j+1] && ((a[j], a[j+1]) = (a[j+1], a[j]))
  end
  return a
end
@btime bubble_sort!(x) setup=(x=copy(y));
#  830.524 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)


function bubble_sort!(a)  # Przemyslaw Szufel
  n = length(a)
  for i in 1:n-1, j in 1:n-i
    a[j] > a[j+1] && (a[j:j+1] .= (a[j+1], a[j]))
  end
  return a
end
@btime bubble_sort!(x) setup=(x=copy(y));
#  1.096 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

function bubble_sort!(a)  # Gwang-Jin Kim
  n = length(a)
  for i in 1:n-1, j in 1:n-i
    a[j], a[j+1] = (a[j] > a[j+1]) ? (a[j+1], a[j]) : (a[j], a[j+1])
  end
  return a
end
@btime bubble_sort!(x) setup=(x=copy(y));
#  1.418 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

function bubble_sort!(a)
  n = length(a)
  for i in 1:n-1, j in 1:n-i
    a[j] > a[j+1] && (a[j:j+1] = a[j+1:-1:j])
  end
  return a
end
@btime bubble_sort!(x) setup=(x=copy(y));
#  15.769 ms (254536 allocations: 19.42 MiB)

function bubble_sort!(a)
  n = length(a)
  for i in 1:n-1, j in 1:n-i
    a[j] > a[j+1] && (a[[j,j+1]] = a[[j+1,j]])
  end
  return a
end
@btime bubble_sort!(x) setup=(x=copy(y));
#  28.967 ms (763608 allocations: 58.26 MiB)
```